# Why is my serializer throwing a TypeError on validated data?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to modify my `EmployeeSerializer` to create a corresponding `User` object when an employee is created. However, in my serializer's `create()` function, I get the following TypeError when I try to save a new object:

```
TypeError: 'skills' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Here's my `Employee` model:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    # ...snip...
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill)
    # ...snip...
```

And here's `EmployeeSerializer`:

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        # Popping 'skills' here prevents the TypeError...
        # skills = validated_data.pop('skills', None)
        employee = Employee(**validated_data)
        employee.save()

        user = UserSerializer(data={
            'username': validated_data.get('email'),
            'password': self.initial_data['password'],
            'groups': self.initial_data['groups'],
            'user_permissions': self.initial_data['user_permissions']
        })

        user.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user.save()

        return employee

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
```

When I call the serializer I declare a `skills` parameter, and it shows up in `validated_data` (note: I trimmed out extraneous Model fields):

```
>>> em = EmployeeSerializer(data={'skills': []})
>>> em.is_valid()
True
>>> em.validated_data
OrderedDict([('skills', [])])
```

Since `skills` is declared in the Model, and it passes the Serializer's validation, I'd expect this new object to save without incident. So what gives? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DRF 3.1 currently does not support write operations for nested representations.**

You will have to handle how to save the nested objects.

From DRF docs on [writable nested representations:](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations)

> The default ModelSerializer `.create()` and `.update()` methods do not
>   include support for writable nested representations.
>
> If you're supporting writable nested representations you'll need to
>   write `.create()` or `.update()` methods that handle saving multiple
>   objects.

You can do something like:

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        skills_data = validated_data.pop('skills') # pop the 'skills' from validated data 
        employee = Employee(**validated_data) # create employee instance            
        employee.save() # save the employee object
        # here you can write the logic to obtain 'skill_object' from 'skills_data' and add them to 'employee' 
        # this can be done iteratively also if there are multiple skills
        employee.skills.add(skill_object) # attach skill object with employee using 'skills_data'
        ...
```

The above constraint for nested representations is only on write operations. So, you were able to get `skills` in `validated_data`.

Comment: Can `skill_object` be the `skills` popped from `validated_data`?

Comment: In response to myself, the answer is no it's not that simple. However you can do a simple `for skill in skills` to iteratively `add()` multiple skills from the `skills` list `pop()`'d from `validated_data`

Comment: Yes, you can use the `skills` popped from `validated_data` if they are the `skill_object`. Also, if there are multiple `skills` popped from `validated_data`, then you can add them iteratively. Slightly modified the ans to include the same.